# Why is the AngularFire chat example breaking?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

As an exercise I was adding email authentication to the base angularFire chat app as seen on [http://angularfire.com/tutorial/](http://angularfire.com/tutorial/#session/c4cb1dbmp9w). 
In the process I noticed deleting the first entry through the forge an undefined entry showed up in the DOM where the 0 entry used to be.

When I deleted the second (id 1) entry nothing showed up due to the following error message: 
*Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: msg in messages key: undefined:undefined*

I noticed the first undefined shows up in the tutorial my code was derived from, but not the second.. until I substitute the .firebaseio-demo.com url with the one to my firebase. This leads me to believe it isn't my implementation of the code.

What is behind the smoke and mirrors of .firebaseio-demo.com that I'm missing?
Is there a mystery validation rule or something?

At some point the Wire up a Backend example on angularjs.org had the same issue.. recently it seems to have been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing, that feels like a bug to me (items deleted from an array in the forge shouldn't be showing up in an `angularFire` bound model array on the client). This effect also doesn't happen when using object collections instead of arrays, e.g. when using `angularFireCollection` or when setting the original `messages` type to an object: `$scope.messages = {}` instead of `$scope.messages = []`.

However, since those deleted items *are* showing up in the resulting array as `undefined`, having more than one `undefined` in your array results in an AngularJS repeater with identical values, which [are not allowed](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/06/15/duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed-in-angularjs/). So the error you are seeing after deleting multiple messages is actually expected.

Regardless, for now it seems like the best ways to avoid it are using object collections instead of arrays as mentioned above or setting up some kind of Angular `filter` to weed out any `undefined` members of your repeater.

Comment: The behavior persists even if you set `$scope.messages = {}`. I created https://chatterr.firebaseio.com/ by importing the demo firebase after adding two more entries from the chat tut, and then deleting the first 2 entries. See if this allows you to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm completely baffled why the behavior would be different between the user created firebase and the demo created firebase.

Comment: You can't switch `$scope.messages` to `{}` on an existing FB location that is already an array, the ref location would need to be initialized that way. But you'd also need to change the way new messages are added since objects don't have the `push` method.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the behaviors of the demo vs normal firebases.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking this was firebase's push() function instead of the push method on arrays. As for normal vs demo the array on demo seems to remove null entries automatically. The normal ones don't as in this export: `[ null, null, { "from" : "foo", "body" : "bar"}, { "from" : "foo",  "body" : "baz"} ]`. Perhaps there is some added logic.

Comment: The push() realization helped alot. Thanks.

Comment: I reintialized the firebase and switched `$scope.messages.push({...})` to `[$scope.name + "-" + Date.now()]={...}` and everything is happily ever after.. for now. Thanks again.

Comment: This definitely seems like a bug though, filed: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/145

Comment: It may not be a angularFire specific issue. In the process I noticed firebase forge will turn a json objects like {"1":{"name":"bob","msg":"hello"}} into [null, {"name":"bob","msg":"hello"}].